# llamar un popup con la función OnClickRow (Javascript).

Tags: javascript, html, mvc, devexpress

Estoy trabajando con devexpress, con esta herramienta creo el popup de la siguiente manera.

```
 @Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "popupCancelar";

                //settings.PopupElementID = "button";
                settings.Width = 700;
                settings.Height = 350;
                settings.Modal = true;
                settings.PopupVerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.WindowCenter;
                settings.PopupHorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.WindowCenter;
                settings.ShowCloseButton = true;
                settings.ShowFooter = false;
                settings.ShowHeader = true;
                settings.AutoUpdatePosition = true;
                settings.FooterText = "";
                settings.HeaderText = "Cancelar cita agendada";




                settings.SetContent(() => ViewContext.Writer.Write
                    (


                      @Html.Partial("~/Views/Admin/_CancelScheduledAppointments.cshtml", null)

                    ));
            }).GetHtml()
```

este popup lo debo abrir desde un botón, así:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="OnClickRow()">  <img src="~/Content/Admin/@lista[i]" style="width: 50px; height: 80px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" /> </a>
```

y se debería llamar desde la función así:

```
 function OnClickRow()
    {

        alert("entro")
        popupCancelar.Show();
    }
```

**problema:** al dar clic en el botón no se muestra el popup, es decir no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable, es que debido al ámbito de la función de *Javascript*, `popupCancelar` no esté definido en la función `OnClickRow`.

Desde la consola del navegador (`F12` en *Chrome*), deberías poder ver si hay algún error al hacer click, como por ejemplo:

> Cannot read `Show` of `undefined` o `Show` is not a function.

*Error traducido al español*:

> No se puede leer `Show` de `undefined` o `Show` no es una función.

Te recomiendo editar el artículo con la información acerca del error, si es que lo hay.